# Magento VM Instance on Google Cloud Platform doesn't allow uploading any files

Tags: cloud, google, magento

Decided to give the [Google Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/explore) a try by launching a one click Magento installation. Everything went smoothly and it did get up and running, however I have encountered one glaring fault that has rendered the whole thing useless- I cannot upload anything.

I have tried uploading via the Magento backend method of going into a static block and clicking the "Insert Image" button and get the following error:
The directory  is not writable by server.

And after hours of troubleshooting SFTP access I did finally get it working through FileZilla only to encounter a similar error:
Error: [file path]: open for write: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed

I'm not sure if similar issues are being run into using Wordpress and other platforms, but just thought I'd give a heads up and see if potentially someone had come up with a fix. Another strange thing is that if you add a product you ARE able to upload images there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the folder permissions; provide write permission for media folders to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The Launcher itself do not provide you with a full working solution. The big question wheither the version of Magento will be up to date and it will be configured properly.

Additionally you have to ensure that you configure networking, firewall, SSH, static IP and security.

I would recommend you to use the cloud deployment services like Deploy4Me instead. You would get a fully configured environment on Google Cloud without extra efforts and you would have people who answer you question just in case. It is a great time saver.